# How to make a json by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html body:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper-items">
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" value="5da1dc651d01" class="idCheck">
      <div class="inner-item">
        <li><input class="SelectdItem" type="checkbox" value="_root.room__0.passenger__1" data-type="2" data-name="test test"></li>
        <li><input class="SelectdItem" type="checkbox" value="_root.room__0.passenger__2" data-type="1" data-name="test2 test2"></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" value="8da1dc651d56" class="idCheck">
      <div class="inner-item">
        <li><input class="SelectdItem" type="checkbox" value="_root.room__0.passenger__1" data-type="2" data-name="test test"></li>
        <li><input class="SelectdItem" type="checkbox" value="_root.room__0.passenger__2" data-type="1" data-name="test2 test2"></li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="handleClick">Check</span>
</div>
```

I want to make a json based on information in html like this :

```js
[{
    sid: "5da1dc651d01",
    passengers: [{
        "room__0.passenger__1": "test test",
        type: "2"
      },
      {
        "room__0.passenger__2": "test2 test2",
        type: "2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    sid: "8da1dc651d56",
    passengers: [
      {
        "room__0.passenger__1": "test test",
        type: "2"
      },
      {
        "room__1.passenger__1": "test2 test2",
        type: "2"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

At first by clicking `handleClick` span the it is checked which one of `idCheck` is checked , then if every one in checked the value is going to be set in object `sid` in `json`. Next `SelectdItem` checkbox is going to be checked, if it is checked the attribute of `value` ,`data-type` and `data-name` will be added in `json` as an array called  `passengers`.
The main problem is that by checking the first `idCheck` ,`json` will be made by one object and there is no problem but by checking the second  `idCheck` , the first object will be removed and second one will be repeated two times.

```
    $(".handleClick").click(function (e) {
    var optionalservices = [];
    var serveiceInfo = {};
    var lenOptional = $(this).closest(".container").find(".item").length;
    for (var i = 1; i <= lenOptional; i++) {
        if ($(this).closest(".container").find(".item:nth-child(" + i + ")").find(".idCheck").is(':checked')) {
            var valueInput = $(this).closest(".container").find(".wrapper-items").find(".item:nth-child(" + i + ")").find(".idCheck").val()
            serveiceInfo["sid"] = valueInput;
            var lenPassengers = $(this).closest(".container").find(".wrapper-items").find(".item:nth-child(" + i + ")").find(".inner-item li").length
            var ArrayPassengers = []
            for (var j = 1; j <= lenPassengers; j++) {
                if ($(this).closest(".container").find(".wrapper-items").find(".item:nth-child(" + i + ")").find(".inner-item li:nth-child(" + j + ")").find(".SelectdItem").is(':checked')) {
                    var key = $(this).closest(".container").find(".wrapper-items").find(".item:nth-child(" + i + ")").find(".inner-item li:nth-child(" + j + ")").find(".SelectdItem").val()
                    var valName = $(this).closest(".container").find(".wrapper-items").find(".item:nth-child(" + i + ")").find(".inner-item li:nth-child(" + j + ")").find(".SelectdItem").attr('data-name')
                    var valType = $(this).closest(".container").find(".wrapper-items").find(".item:nth-child(" + i + ")").find(".inner-item li:nth-child(" + j + ")").find(".SelectdItem").attr('data-type')
                    ObjPassenger = {}
                    ObjPassenger[key] = valName
                    ObjPassenger["type"] = valType
                    ArrayPassengers.push(ObjPassenger)

                }
                serveiceInfo["passengers"] = ArrayPassengers
            }
            optionalservices.push(serveiceInfo)
        }

    }


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is `mutation` of `seviceInfo` you update `serviceInfo` and push to `optionalservices` array but reference of `serviceInfo` remain same thats the issue.

Here's fixed code

```
$('.handleClick').click(function(e) {
  var optionalservices = [];
  var lenOptional = $(this)
    .closest('.container')
    .find('.item').length;
  for (var i = 0; i < lenOptional; i++) {
    var selectedItem = $(this)
      .closest('.container')
      .find('.item')
      .eq(i);
    var serveiceInfo = {};
    if (selectedItem.find('.idCheck').is(':checked')) {
      var valueInput = selectedItem.find('.idCheck').val();
      serveiceInfo['sid'] = valueInput;
      var lenPassengers = selectedItem.find('.inner-item li').length;
      var ArrayPassengers = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < lenPassengers; j++) {
        var selectedChild = selectedItem.find('.inner-item li').eq(j);
        if (
          selectedItem
            .find('.inner-item li')
            .eq(j)
            .find('.SelectdItem')
            .is(':checked')
        ) {
          var key = selectedChild.find('.SelectdItem').val();
          var valName = selectedChild.find('.SelectdItem').attr('data-name');
          var valType = selectedChild.find('.SelectdItem').attr('data-type');
          ObjPassenger = {};
          ObjPassenger[key] = valName;
          ObjPassenger['type'] = valType;
          ArrayPassengers.push(ObjPassenger);
        }
        serveiceInfo['passengers'] = ArrayPassengers;
      }
      optionalservices.push(serveiceInfo);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be doing it a little bit different and more readable

```
const objectArray = new Array();
$('.wrapper-items item').each(function(){
  const checkboxValue = this.find('input#idCheck').val();
  let currentObject = new Object();
  currentObject.passengers = new Array();
  currentObject.sid = checkboxValue;

  this.find('.inner-item input:checked').each(function(){
    let passengerObject = new Object();
    passengerObject[this.val()] = this.attr('data-name');
    passengerObject['type'] = this.attr('type');
    currentObject.passengers.push(passengerObject);
  })

  objectArray.push(currentObject);
})

///objectArray will contain the data.
```